# Return view use Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ext.net

I want to call a view using Ajax script:

In main view:

```
<script>
    var onCommand = function (column, command, record, recordIndex, cellIndex) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('record = ' + record.data.ID);
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/Details/',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                id: record.data.ID
            },

            success: function (response) {
                var result = (response.responseText);
                if (result != "") {
                    modelName = result;
                    CreateLookUp(combo, id, false, true);
                } else {

                    CreateLookUp(combo, id, true, false);
                }
            }
        });

            }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
  // GET: Bob/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(String ID)
        {
           int  id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            BobRepository bobRepository = new BobRepository();
            Bob bob = bobRepository.GetBob(id);
            if (bob == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(bob);
        }
```

The function call of the controller is called, the turget view is not returned. What is the reason?

Comment: Do a `console.log(response)` inside the success handler and check it is the expected output. Also, you should return a partial view result for an ajax call.

Comment: Yes. Respons return all html code.

Comment: Then what you mean by **the turget view is not returned** ???

Comment: In the browser, I stay on the old view. I need to switch to a new one, the code of which was returned in the answer.

Comment: If you want to switch to a full new view, why are you making an ajax call ? Why not a normal form submit and let the server return a redirect result ? The whole point of ajax is to give partial page update to the user . Also looks like you are calling some other method `CreateLookUp`. We do not know what is inside that and what it is supposed to do. Only you know!

Comment: I try do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113741/function-asp-net-not-return-view

Comment: View not return.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, I am assuming you are filling that view in some pop up modal, first you need to return partial view instead of view, i suggest checking if the request [is ajax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest(v=vs.118).aspx) then return partial view else return view,
something like this

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{return PartialView(bob);}
else
return View(bob);
```

in your js, parse the text to html, you can use [jquery.htmlparse](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

```
  success: function (response) {
                var result =  $.parseHTML(response);
                //do what you want with your html
```

Comment: I'm trying to call a presentation on the face of the GridVew.